# Google Optimize цели из Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

Как правильно вставлять цели в Google Optimize из Google Analytics
Создал цель
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ссылках которые должны отслеживаться - вставил `onClick="gtag('event','buttons', {event_action:'click'});"`

В гугл оптимайз - выбрал цель[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таг менеджере есть два теги: аналитики и оптимайза. Последний запускается выше аналитики

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На странице есть скрипт таг менеджера:

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-57KXPFB');</script>
```

Проблема в том, что при запуске теста, аналитика видит пользователей но не видит переходы по ссылкам.... Уже неделю не могу понять что делаю не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с моего сайта

`onclick="gtag('event', 'openvkGroup', { 'event_category': 'VkGroup', 'event_action': 'click', });"`

openvkGroup - произвольное название

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у вас это все работает через Google Tag Manager?

Comment: `gtag` как видите, да )

Comment: Ну просто вот у меня в аналитике данные по посещению есть - а вот цели 0! Не понимаю почему так...

Comment: сравните свою метку и мою. у вас так же заполнена?

Comment: да, только что поменял у тебя и теперь все как у вас, только мои данные...

Comment: ссылку на сайт подкиньте пожалуйста

Comment: это локальный сайт. На время эксперимента я его посадил на ngrok домен. Подскажите, можно  с вами как то связаться? Мне очень нужна помощь в этом деле :(

Comment: конечно, контакты мои на сайте есть. сайт в профиле

Comment: Проблема балы с Google Tag Manager... Он попросту не подключал оптимайз и задачу из аналитики. Добавил скрипт оптимайза отдельно (аналитика - в сборке с Google Tag Manager) -  и все заработало!